# Smoke rendering as the domain box in grey within Cycles Render

Tags: rendering

None of the previous questions have answered my issue.

The elements of this project were all created whilst in Cycles Render mode. 
No node information has been produced as a result of using  Quick smoke.

Any Ideas?

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure, did you switch to Cycles before or after you set up Quick Smoke? Quick Smoke creates the domain's material according to which render engine is active when it's called.